# Populating "data" section of a post request with function

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib2, urllib

Trying to populate the "data" section of a urllib request in python with values from a list, and some formatting.

Say I have a list like this `[1492, 1493, 1493, ...]`

and I want to get those two values into the following:

```
data = ({
    'c_id': '458',
    'state': 'live',
    'spec_ids[]': '1492',
    'spec_ids[]': '1493',
    'spec_ids[]': '1494',
    'spec_ids[]': '...',
    'allow_undo': 'true',
    'flash': 'False'
    })
```

and they have to have the format of `'spec_ids[]': '####'`

What's the simplest/best way to do so?

I want the solution to be scalable so that as the list becomes longer it continues to add values to the submitted data.

Any and all help is appreciated. I'm really stuck here and have tried a number of different things that have all failed.

Comment: Dictionary can't have duplicated keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries can't have duplicate values, but `urllib.urlencode` accepts any iterable object, so we can use lists to achieve the functionality we need.

```
import urllib

data = [
    ('c_id', '458'),
    ('state', 'live'),
    ('flash', 'False')
] + [ ('spec_ids[]',str(x)) for x in [1492, 1493, 1493] ]

print urllib.urlopen("http://stackoverflow.com/",urllib.urlencode(data)).read()
```

This uses a list generator to create `'spec_ids[]'` fields from our data list. Note that this will be a POST request due to the use of urlopen's data parameter.

Comment: +1 I completely missed the parts where the OP was asking for a `urllib` solution. Time for bed I think..